# Magento 2 Order Object Error

Tags: magento2, module, orders

I am trying to retrieve information about an order to display a custom success page.  I have a custom module setup extending

```
\Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
```

and it is working perfectly fine.  Below is my code used to call the order information.

```
    public function orderListings($ID)
            {
                echo $ID;
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($ID);
                $class_methods = get_class_methods($order);
                $totall = $order->getGrandTotal();
                echo "Order Total:".$totall."<br/>";
}
```

I am calling this method in my custom success.phtml template, where I can access the getOrderId() method of the $block object:

```
$ID = $block->getOrderId();
$block->orderListings($ID);
```

However, whenever I call my custom method orderListings and pass in the order ID, the method fails to function properly and won't retrieve the correct order information.  No errors are thrown, the $totall variable just simply is empty.  If I call the same method and statically enter an order Id,

```
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load(000000146);
```

then it functions properly and outputs the grand total.

When I echo the $ID variable, it is the exact same as the number I entered manually.  What could possibly be causing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**load** method loads data by primary_key by default. So you always try to load by order entity_id not increment_id. So you need to change by :

```
$id = 1;
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($id);
```

For your case you should go following way :

```
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId(000000146);
```

Comment: I love you so much.  Works as expected.  This was the final piece of making my module work.  Yay.